# php database connection error for changing port number

Tags: php, database-connection

I am facing database connection problem while trying to connect a .php file through wamp server
the error message is something like- "Access denied for the user " @ ' localhost' " for database
 'aschool'. 'aschool' is my database name.
Mentioning that I've changed my port number of wamp server, I am worried that is it really
for changing port number or anything else.Here is my code.

```
$con = mysql_connect();
if (!$con)
{
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db("aschool", $con);
```

After this line the error message comes. I've tried parameters "localhost" inside the mysql_connect()
function or more parameters but the result is same.
Thanks in advance anyone gives me any solution

Comment: The "wamp" server uses several port numbers for several different tasks.  What port number did you change?

Comment: Also, have you checked your connection credentials with a second source?

Comment: find the `my.cnf` or `my.ini` file somewhere in the wamp directory. Then find the port number it listens on. Then use that port number in `mysql_connect` in `host:port` format.

Comment: Did you try to log in with your Command prompt ? Did you succeed ?

Answer (score 2):

That's because you are using `mysql_connect`wrong for your use case.

If you [check the documentation page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php) it says that you can also a server-path,
something like `mysql_connect('localhost:1234', 'username', 'password')`.

**But you shouldn't use `mysql_connect`.**

[Use PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.construct.php) so that you can use parameterized queries.

In code it would go like this:

```
try
{
  $pdo = new \PDO('mysql:dbname=aschool;host=127.0.0.1', 'myUser', 'myPassword');
} catch (PDOException $exception)
{
  // Do something with your exception.
  // Echo it, dump it, log it, die it.
  // Just don't ignore the exceptions!
}
```

Comment: @polin I just showed you. All you have to fill in is `myUser` and `myPassword`